# pattern check using awk

Tags: python, awk, data-science

Is there a way to use awk or python to check patterns, in our group we have 120,000 lines messages but what to know who replies after who the most;

Consider the following lines;

- AA
- BB
- AA
- CC
- AA
- BB
- AA
- AA
- AA
- BB
- CC
- AA

I would want the result to show

- AA->BB = 3
- BB->AA = 2
- AA->CC = 1
- CC->AA = 2
- AA->CC = 1
- BB->CC = 1
- CC->BB = 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might be sufficient for you:

```
$ awk 'NR > 1 && prev != $1 { sum[prev"->"$1]++ }
       { prev = $1 }
       END { for (a in sum) { print a" = "sum[a] } }
  ' input.txt
AA->CC = 1
BB->AA = 2
AA->BB = 3
BB->CC = 1
CC->AA = 2
```

- Sorting is random,
- it doesn't print `AA->CC = 1` twice ;)
- and it doesn't print empty relations `CC->BB = 0`

Comment: ++ for _it doesn't print AA->CC = 1 twice ;)_ :D :D

Comment: Amazing thanks, works just great: i can now use this to do counts of who replied to who in whatsapp messages

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v OFS="=" '                           # set for one single use
{
    if(FNR>1 && p!=$0)                       # exclude unwanted
        a[p "->" $0]++                       # count
    p=$0                                     # save $0 for next round
}
END {                                        # in the end
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"    # ordering in GNU awk
    for(i in a)                              # We loop
        print i,a[i]                         # and count
}' file
```

Output:

```
AA->BB=3
BB->AA=2
CC->AA=2
AA->CC=1
BB->CC=1
```

If you want the output sorted and not the implementation related awk default and you are using GNU awk, use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"`. If not, remove the line and pipe the output to `sort -t= -k2n`